# Fourier series for $\cos(x)$ from $[-\pi,\pi ]$

Tags: sequences-and-series

As Fourier converts waves into sines and cosines, I know that the answer will be the same function $\cos(x)$... but I'm confused in computing the coefficients!

Comment: The coefficients can be calculated as usual.

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine the Fourier coefficients $a_k$, $b_k$ the hard way you have to compute the integrals
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos x\>\cos(kx)\>dx,\qquad \int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos x\>\sin(kx)\>dx\qquad(k\geq0)\ .$$
All but one of these $2\cdot\infty$ integrals  are $=0$ on account of the orthogonality relations, and it remains $a_1=1$.